# where does topology of CW complex come from

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

When my professor was talking about CW complex, he made this comment: $X^n = (X^{n-1} \sqcup D^{n}_\alpha)/~$, the $X^{n-1} \sqcup D^{n}_\alpha$ is disjoint union as a set, and has no topology. My question is that since $X^n$ is a topological space under quotient topology map, where does its topology come from? I mean if a set is open in $X^n$, you need to pull it back to its preimage in $(X^{n-1} \sqcup D^{n}_\alpha)/~$ and show that it is open in there, but $(X^{n-1} \sqcup D^{n}_\alpha)$ has no topology?

Comment: Not sure what your professor was trying to say, but there is a natural topology on the disjoint union: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union_(topology)

Comment: He mentioned that if you take a sequence in $D^n_\alpha$ converges to the boundary, the point of convergence is not in the $e^n_\alpha$ cell

Comment: Of course the disjoint union has a topology. You should ask your professor what he *really* wanted to say.